# How to Monitor CPU and GPU usage for a specific amount of time

Tags: cpu-load

I want to have the log of CPU and GPU usage for the past 24 hours, if possible or for a specific period of time

Answer (score 1):

sysstat is in the apt repository....

`sudo apt-get install sysstat`

A lot of available and specific configuration, but just from the man pages I was able to quickly generate:

```
wu-tang:~$ sar -u 2 5

Linux 5.4.0-51-generic (WuMachine)  10/27/2020  _x86_64_    (2 CPU)

01:33:22 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
01:33:24 AM     all      2.27      0.00      2.02      0.00      0.00     95.71
01:33:26 AM     all      1.27      0.00      1.02      0.00      0.00     97.71
01:33:28 AM     all      1.26      0.00      0.76      0.00      0.00     97.98
01:33:30 AM     all      1.01      0.00      0.50      0.00      0.00     98.49
01:33:32 AM     all      1.50      0.00      0.25      0.00      0.00     98.25
Average:        all      1.46      0.00      0.91      0.00      0.00     97.63
```